# Multi Threading and Task issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is the first time I'm attempting multiple threads in a project so bear with me.  The idea is this.  I have a bunch of documents I need converted to pdf.  I am using itextsharp to do the conversion for me.  When run iteratively, the program runs fine but slow.

I have a list of items that need to be converted.  I take that list and split it into 2 lists.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < essaylist.Count / 2; i++)
                {                        
                    frontessay.Add(essaylist[i]);
                    try
                    {
                        backessay.Add(essaylist[essaylist.Count - i]);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
                if (essaylist.Count > 1)
                {
                    var essay1 = new Essay();
                    Thread t1 = new Thread(() => essay1.StartThread(frontessay));
                    Thread t2 = new Thread(() => essay1.StartThread(backessay));

                    t1.Start();
                    t2.Start();

                    t1.Join();
                    t2.Join();
                }
                else
                {
                    var essay1 = new Essay();
                    essay1.GenerateEssays(essaylist[1]);
                }
```

I then create 2 threads that run this code

```
    public void StartThread(List<Essay> essaylist)
    {
        var essay = new Essay();
        List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> tasklist = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
        int threadcount = 7;
        Boolean threadcomplete = false;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < essaylist.Count; i++)
        {               
            essay = essaylist[i];
            var task1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => essay.GenerateEssays(essay));
            tasklist.Add(task1);
            counter++;
            if (tasklist.Count % threadcount == 0)
            {
                tasklist.ForEach(t => t.Wait());
                //counter = 0;
                tasklist = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
                threadcomplete = true;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        tasklist.ForEach(t => t.Wait());
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

For the majority of the files, the code runs as it should.  However, for example I have 155 items that need to be convereted.  When the program finishes and I look at the results I have 149 items instead of 155.  It seems like the results are something like the total = list - threadcount.  In this case its 7.  Any ideas on how to correct this?  Am I even doing threads/tasks correctly?

Also the essay.GenerateEssays code is the actual itextsharp that converts the info from the db to the actual pdf.

Comment: Try either having Visual Studio catch all exceptions (Debug->Exceptions, check EVERYTHING) or put in your own try-catch-expose statement in the task call...exceptions in side threads don't automatically crash the program (which is dumb, but understandable), so what could (emphasis on the "this might not be it") be happening is that some of your tasks are crashing.

Comment: This shouldn't cause you to be off by as much as you are, but I believe you should have [for (int i = 0; i <= essaylist.Count / 2; i++)] on the first line.

Comment: for splitting the list you can use: `front = essayList.Take(essayList.Count / 2); back = essayList.Skip(essayList.Count / 2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It seems that all your code can be replaced with this

```
Parallel.ForEach(essaylist, essay =>
{
    YourAction(essay);
});
```

Comment: @Marco and `Parallel.ForEach` waits all the work to finish :)

Comment: This seems to work just fine.  I wish I didnt spend a few days trying to figure it out.  thank you

Comment: i am.  But honestly, I've spent a lot of time trying to figure the problem out.  I'm just glad there was a solution that stops me from banging my head on the table.